# Creating a record in one table will update an existing record in another table ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC and I wanted to know how to create a new record in one table and update an existing record in another table for example I have two tables `Asset Master` and `Assigning Asset` so when creating a record in `Assigning Asset` with employee name (eg. Hana) and asset code (eg. Lap001) it should search in `Asset Master` table if the asset code exist update employee name if not throw error I have searched for the solution but couldn't find the answer

`AssigningAssetModel` class:

```
public class AssigningAssetModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Employee Name")]
    public string Employee Name{ get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter AssetCode")]
    public string AssetCode { get; set; }
}
```

`AssetMasterModel` class:

```
public class AssetMasterModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get ;set; }

    public string AssetCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string EmployeeName{ get; set; }
}
```

`AssigningAsset` controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<iactionresult> Create(int id [Bind("ID,EmployeeName,AssetCode")] AssigningAssetModel assigningAssetModel)
{
        if (id != assigningAssetModel.ID)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(assigningAssetModel);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!AssigningAssetModelExists(assigningAssetModel.ID))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        return View(assigningAssetModel);
}
```

How to pass `AssetCode` here so I can update the existing record in `AssetMaster` table?

Note that if the asset code is not found it should not create new record in `AssetMaster` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if (id != assigningAssetModel.ID) return NotFound();

 if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(assigningAssetModel);

 try
   {
              
 var masterExist= await _context.Set<AssetMasterModel>().FirstOrDefaultAsync( i=>i.AssetCode ==assigningAssetModel.AssetCode );

 if(masterExist==null) return NotFound();

  if( masterExist.EmployeeName!=assigningAssetModel.EmployeeName)
   {
    masterExist.EmployeeName=assigningAssetModel.EmployeeName;
     _context.Entry(masterExist).State=EntityState.Modified;
    }
_context.Add(assigningAssetModel);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   
  _context.Update(assigningAssetModel);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  }
 catch ( Exception ex)
       {
 return  BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }

   return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
```